# Why can't I pass this prop to the child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-props

I've been having a problem with React Route. I can pass pass2Parent={this.pass2Parent} to the Search component, but I can't pass data={data} to the Result component.

I've been researching the problem for hours and I've explored using render instead of component in the route. Unfortunately, it had the side effect of calling an API multiple times and burning through my allowance.

I just don't get why it's not working as it is..

```
render() {
  let data = this.state;
  console.log(data);

  return (
    <div style={{height: "inherit"}}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/' exact component={() => <Search pass2Parent={this.pass2Parent}/>}/>
          <Route path='/result' exact component={(data) => <Result data={data}/>}/>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is what console.log(data) returns:

```
{
  images: {total: 8327, total_pages: 833, results: Array(10)},
  weather: {coord: {…}, weather: Array(1), base: "stations", main: {…}, visibility: 10000, …}
}
```

This is what console.log(this.props) looks like in the child component:

```
{
  data: {
    history: {length: 2, action: "POP", location: {…}, createHref: ƒ, push: ƒ, …},
    location: { pathname: "/result", search: "", hash: "", state: undefined },
    match: { path: "/result", url: "/result", isExact: true, params: {…} },
    staticContext: undefined,
  }
}
```

Comment: By specifying a `data` argument to your inline component you're shadowing the local `data` variable. Inside your inline component, the props object is called "data". Omit the data argument: `component={() => <Result data={data} />`

Comment: When does the data become available?  Is it immediately available on render of the  `<Result />` component?  Or is it fetched later?

Comment: @rayhatfield I just changed it to <Route path='/result' exact component={() => <Result data={this.state}/>}/>,The same issue came up, that in the child component. console.log(this.props) --> {data: {…}} data: proto: Object proto: Object

Answer (score 1):

the argument `data` passed into your `component={(data)=>` is a SyntheticEvent, that inside it scope overwrite the `data` value from state. Delete the argument and that it...

---

```
<Route path='/result' exact component={() => <Result data={data}/>}/>
```

---

Comment: I just changed it to <Route path='/result' exact component={() => <Result data={this.state}/>}/>,The same issue came up, that in the child component.
console.log(this.props) -->

{data: {…}}
data:
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object

Comment: Why `data={this.state}` and not `data={this.state.data}`

Comment: Because this.state is an object with two keys, weather and images. "Data" doesn't exist in the state.

See console.log(data) to see the contents of this.state.

Comment: Before it was `data`, refer to state... and if you need to pull something from an object accord key, `data[weather]`